# Loading large image in Tkinter causes MemoryError

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter, out-of-memory, tkinter-canvas

My background is that I am a microbiologist who is self-taught in programming. If there are easier ways to do this or ways to clean up my code I am always open to constructive criticism and ways to improve. I am trying to create a GUI using python's tkinter using the code below:

```
import sys
import cv2

from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2

class TypeOneDetectionEditor(object):
    def __init__(self):

        image_file = "6wk_Control_B_01.png"  # Update the file as needed

        self.image_cv = cv2.imread(image_file)
        self.resize_factor = 0.1
        self.height, self.width, self.channel = self.image_cv.shape

        self.window = Tk()
        self.frame = Frame(self.window, bd=5, relief = SUNKEN)

        # Hard-code choice of resolution for canvas and scroll region as
        # maximum shape of images*resize_factor
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg="#000000", width=1366, height=768,
                             scrollregion=(0, 0, self.width*self.resize_factor,
                                           self.height*self.resize_factor))

        # Scrollbars
        hbar=Scrollbar(self.frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        hbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        vbar=Scrollbar(self.frame,orient=VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        vbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

        # Img + Event listeners
        # Literally because tkinter can't handle references properly and needs this.
        self.canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(self.image_cv))
        # So we can change the image later
        self.canvas_image_config = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0,
                                                            image=self.canvas.image,
                                                            anchor="nw")
        # Sets the focus to our program besides putting it in the background
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        # Put future functions here
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.window.mainloop()

TypeOneDetectionEditor()
```

The error that I am recieving states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bacterial Counter GUI.py", line 45, in <module>
    TypeOneDetectionEditor()
  File "Bacterial Counter GUI.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(self.image_cv))#Literally because tkinter can't handle references properly and needs this.
  File "C:\Users\basay3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "C:\Users\basay3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 175, in paste
    block = image.new_block(self.__mode, im.size)
MemoryError
```

I have updated both my tkinter and pillow libraries but that still has not solved the problem. The image I am trying to use is 604 MB (too big to upload to this post) and I have 16 GB of ram on my computer. I am at a loss of what is happening so any advice at this point would be helpful.

Comment: 604MB, is that the file size, the pixel count, the memory used, something else?

Comment: 604MB isn't really that big for an image file. Does this work OK with smaller images?

Comment: Please explain **why** do you use `cv2.imread(...` as first step. This will double the image in memory. Tkinter can handle `PNG` images by it's own.

Comment: What is the resolution of the image? Although the file size is not too big, but if the resolution of the image is too high, then the memory usage for the output of `cv2.imread()` may be high.  Same for the memory usage for  the output of `Image.fromarray(...)` and `ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)`.

Comment: 604MB is the file size and it does work correctly with smaller images. The Image size is 1832526150 and the shape is (22450, 27209, 3). Thanks for your responses.